# how to access through each factor element within a list through for loop in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a variable like below

```
dput(hour)
structure(1:12, .Label = c("07AM_08AM", "08AM_09AM", "09AM_10AM", 
"10AM_11AM", "11AM_12PM", "12PM_1PM", "1PM_2PM", "2PM_3PM", "3PM_4PM", 
"4PM_5PM", "5PM_6PM", "6PM_7PM"), class = "factor")
```

```
data:
dput(head(data,2))
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = c("2017-01-01", 
"2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04"), class = "factor"), hour = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("07AM_08AM", "08AM_09AM", "09AM_10AM", "10AM_11AM", 
"11AM_12PM", "12PM_1PM", "1PM_2PM", "2PM_3PM", "3PM_4PM", "4PM_5PM", 
"5PM_6PM", "6PM_7PM"), class = "factor"), weekday = structure(c(4L, 
4L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I have to fill missing dates using pad function by each hour.I created loop for that.

```
for(m in 1: length(hour)){
  print(hour[m])
  pad_data <- pad(data,end_val =Sys.Date()-1)
}
```

```
Output: pad_data:
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTT9s.png
```

which works fine.Now, i want to create a function for reuse purpose.I have created like below.

```
imputing_variables=list(independent_Variable='hour')
datesfun<-function(data,imputing_variables){
   for(i in 1:length(imputing_variables$independent_Variable)){
    i=1
    print(i)
    pad_data<-pad(data,end_val =Sys.Date()-1)
  }
  return pad_data
}
```

when i print `length(imputing_variables$independent_Variable)
[1] 1` getting like this.It is not giving elements present in the hour. 
I tried like this also

```
imputing_variables$independent_Variable[[1]]
[1] "hour"
```

Tried this also

```
 imputing_variables$independent_Variable[1][[1]]
[1] "hour"
```

Please,suggest me how to access those hour element present in the list in R

Comment: From where is `pad` function from? How does your expected output `pad_data` look ? How do you run the `for` loop which works fine ?

Comment: Your list is not doing what you think. `imputing_variables=list(independent_Variable='hour')` is creating a list of one element `hour` with column name `independent_Variable`. If you're wanting to access `hour` as a coulmn in a dataframe, you should call it like `list(independent_Variable = df$hour)`

Comment: Also, in your for loop you are overriding the value of `i` when you put `i=1`.

Comment: pad function is from tidyverse library.Hour is not a dataframe column it is a factor.

Comment: You say that your `for` loop works fine. Can you show how you run it? If I run it using the data you have shared now, it gives me error stating `Error: x should be a data frame.`

Comment: Can i put output of for loop?

Comment: Yes and also clarify what is `data` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Ok.I'll edit my question

Comment: I included data as well as sample output

Comment: Pad function is from padr library not from tidyverse

Comment: Do you really need `for` loop or this? Can't you just do `padr::pad(data,end_val =Sys.Date()-1)` ? I think it gives the same result.

Comment: For loop is needed for another operations in the function.